# How to run aws cli inside docker container running on ec2 instance that has attached to ec2 read iam policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm working on a project where I've to use aws cli inside a docker container. Now my host ec2 instance is running on Ubuntu 22 and is attached to iam role that allow read access to all resources of ec2 service using default ec2 read policy. The host instance is working properly and can access all the read queries but the docker container is not able to access the data and is getting this error.

`An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

The IAM policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need help how can I fix this issue and can able to run aws cli inside container? I know that we can get manual access key and secret key but for the sake of security, I need to use this way. Please help me.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce, but didn't succeed, `docker run -it --rm amazon/aws-cli ec2 describe-instances` works as well as just `aws ec2 describe-instances`. How are you running the container?

Comment: I'm running a Jenkins docker container inside an ec2 instance. The curl command `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` works fine inside the container but it doesn't work when I'm trying to describe ec2 instances.

Comment: Try comparing the output of `aws configure list --debug` on the instance and inside the container, it may give you some insight. It shows which credentials are used. You should see something like `Found credentials from IAM Role: <role_name>`.

Comment: This seem like just a question about configuring the AWS CLI or an EC2 instance profile; is there any relevant application source code that would make this a question about programming?  Why use the AWS CLI inside a container, instead of the native AWS SDK for the language your application uses?